# Битовые операции в динамическом программиовании

Tags: алгоритм, битовые-операции, динамическое-программирование

задача про [симпатичные узоры](http://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=83)

при решении используются битовые операции, в которых ничего не знаю. Есть ли способ заменить этот код, который занимает много времени через какой нибудь программерский(битовые операции типа &, <<, >>) способ?

```css
  for(i=0;i<=m-2;i++){
    string k1 =  bitset<30>(p1).to_string();
      reverse(k1.begin(), k1.end());
    string k3 =  bitset<30>(p2).to_string();
 reverse(k3.begin(), k3.end());
    b[1] = k1.at(i);
    b[2] =  k1.at(i+1);
    b[3] = k3.at(i);
    b[4] =  k3.at(i+1);
    if (b[1] == '1' && b[2] == '1' && b[3] =='1' && b[4] == '1'){
// квадрат в строках i и i + 1 чрный
xx = false;

}
if ((b[1] == '0') &&(b[2] == '0') && (b[3] == '0') && (b[4] == '0')) {
// квадрат в строках i и i + 1 белый
xx = false;

}
    
  }
  
  return xx;
}
```

Comment: Мда, жесть. кто интересно придумал так работать с битами. это даже битовыми операциями не назовешь. тут их как строки обрабатывают... И да, вы правы, если это обрабатывать как двочиные числа скорость будет на несколько порядков выше.Собственно, что вы не понимаете в этом коде ? Главное научиться reverse делать. а остальное то вообще ерунда, взяли пару бит из одного числа, пару из другого, убедились что результат 0b1111 или 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку есть ограничение на размер 30, то можно хранить срез в 32-разрядном целом числе. Выделение i-го бита:

```
bit(v, i) = (v >> i) & 1;
```

А проверка на все черные или белые:

```
if ((bit1 || bit2 || bit3 || bit4) == 0) 
if ((bit1 && bit2 && bit3 && bit4) == 1)
```

Ещё вариант одновременной проверки и на черный, и на белый квадрат:

```
if (((bit1 + bit2 + bit3 + bit4) & 3) == 0)
```